# Microsoft Access Send email to Client and get Email address from database

Tags: database, forms, email, object, ms-access

Gday all,

I'm trying to send a Report from Microsoft Access to a Client.

So i have a client table with the client details including an email address etc..

And in my form i am using a button linked to a macro that creates the report and sends it via email using "EMailDatabaseObject"
However this way i cannot select the email address from the list in my clients section i have to type one in the macro builder or leave blank and get prompted for it.

Is there anyway that i could have a Select Query linked to the "to" section of EMailDatabaseObject?

Or is there another way i should be trying to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```
Public Sub cmdTerms_Click()

Dim objOutlook As New Outlook.Application
Dim objMail As MailItem
Dim KnownAs As String
Dim Eml As String
Dim Text As String
Dim PathName As String
Dim PathName2 As String
Dim Quest As Integer
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

DoCmd.TransferText acExportMerge, "", "qryTerms", conAddrPth & "\DataSource.txt", True, "", 1252
```

Me.DocName = conAddrPth & "\DBS Service Agreement.docm"
OpenWordDoc

```
KnownAs = DLookup("Fname", "qryTerms")
Eml = DLookup("Email", "qryTerms")
Text = "Dear " & KnownAs & vbCr & vbCr & "I'd be grateful if you would read the attached Code of Practice and " & _
   "Service Level Agreement." & vbCr & vbCr & _
   "If you are happy with these terms please complete, sign and return pages one and " & _
   "two of the attachment. " & vbCr & vbCr & "Please let me know if you have any questions or concerns." & vbCr & vbCr & _
   "With best wishes." & vbCr & vbCr & EmailSig

PathName = conAddrPth & "\DBS Service Agreement.pdf"

Set objOutlook = New Outlook.Application
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With objMail
.To = Eml
.Subject = "DBS Checking Service"
.Body = Text
.NoAging = True
.Attachments.Add PathName
.Display (True)
End With

Set objMail = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

It's something I use. The above would be a procedure on your form. The form would have data such as the address etc. I would employ Word Mail Merge to make a report (or letter). It would be just as easy to send a report if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is in VBA, you can convert your report creation macro  to VBA code and add this after the generated code

```
Dim vRecipient As String
Dim vMsg As String
Dim vSubject As String

vMsg = " Your Message here... "
vSubject = " Your Subject here... "
vRecipient = "x@x.xxx" 'probably it is best to select from some listbox 


DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, " rptYourReport ", acFormatPDF, vRecipient, , , vSubject, vMsg, False
```

Also  you can see [here](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=251989)